# STEM competitions in Ivory Coast

Tags: usa, france, students

I am an expat high-schooler currently based in Abidjan, Ivory Coast. I am looking for recognized STEM competitions or programs (such as Science Olympiads) within my geographical region so that I can build a good profile before my college applications. Any leads? I haven't been able to find any interesting things online so far.

Could also be online.

Comment: The [Expatriates Help page](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help) says this site is not for "General questions about living in a country, which would similarly apply to a local citizen and not just for expats. Please add specifics to the question that describes why you think your issue is specific _because you are an expatriate_, otherwise your question will likely be closed." This question would apply to any Ivory Coast student who wants a STEM education; it doesn't require being a citizen of somewhere other than Ivory Coast. Thus, it's off-topic here. I voted to close.